# C# ReplicationManager Error - ConfigurationErrorsException

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to connect to a MYSQL Database

Using the MysqlConnector plugin
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/

```html
var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Server = "127.0.0.1",
    UserID = "root",
    Password = "",
    Database = "projet hsv",
};
```

with

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
```

I have the error

```
'The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.'


ConfigurationErrorsException : Unrecognized configuration section system.data
```

I tried searching other stackoverflow issues and uninstalling Mysql.data but nothing happens. The `Open()` method displays this error.

Comment: i ran your code and it runs with 127.0.0.1 and with localhost, there must be another cause for that error. Maybe a new start would help you

Comment: same erreur using the 'localhost'

Comment: i use visual studio 2022 latest update, check your visual studio installer for updates and also the nuget management if there are updates

Comment: is the latest version of visual studio and no nuget package need upgrade

Comment: then start a new project and only add the connector and the code provided and then add the rest slowly

Comment: Is it legal to have a space in the database name?

Comment: With and without space is same error

Comment: If you're using MySqlConnector, it's not possible to get an exception from `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager`, unless you're _also_ using that library. Make sure `MySql.Data` is completely uninstalled and add the full exception call stack to your question: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/.